# RequireJs is breaking my for loop when combining files (r.js)

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using RequireJs and for production releases combining/minify-ing and uglify-ing it using r.js, but have run into a bug related to how it handles one of my FOR loops.

I turned off all optimizations on the r.js build so now it is only combining the code into one file, but not minifying/uglifying; however, the bug persists.

Original (simplified) Code:

```
var myArray = ['item1', 'apple', 'item2', 'item3', 'bread', 'etc'];

//remove items from array according to some complex logic
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

  var cur = myArray[i];

  if (cur.indexOf('item') === 0) { //if starts with "item" remove it
    myArray.splice(i, 1);
    i--; //*IMPORTANT* Move index back to avoid skipping next item
    continue;
  }

  //do unrelated processing
}

//now use the array
alert(myArray);
```

Orig Code Output:

```
['apple', 'bread', 'etc']
```

This code works correctly as written. However, when i run it through r.js (with optimize: "none") it outputs this code which doesn't work as intended:

r.js output code:

```
var myArray = ['item1', 'apple', 'item2', 'item3', 'bread', 'etc'];


var _loop = function _loop(_i) {
  var cur = myArray[_i];

  if (cur.indexOf('item') === 0) {
    myArray.splice(_i, 1);
    _i--;
    return 'continue';
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  var _ret = _loop(i);

  if (_ret === 'continue') continue;
}

alert(myArray);
```

r.js Code Output:

```
['apple', 'item3', 'bread', 'etc']
```

As you can see the code is **nearly** identical, but because the r.js moved my for loop into a function, I can't alter the index so after removing/splicing a value and moving back the index, that change to the index is lost entirely and the next item in the array is skipped.

**Work Arounds**

I could loop the index back to front so I don't need to alter the index, but I'm performing other calculations that need to be done in order (front-to-back).  Plus I'm worried about this bug sneaking into my code in the future.

**Questions**

Is this how r.js is supposed to work (did i miss a simple setting)?

Am I coding in an anti-pattern and should change my approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Doing a straightforward run with `r.js -o name=src/module out=build.js optimize=none` (with `src/module.js` containing your code), I can't reproduce the problem you describe. The module is put as-is into `build.js` and `define("src/module", function(){});` is added after the module, which is normal as the module is not actually AMD and thus the optimizer has to generate a `define` for it. Maybe there are important details missing from your question. I'd suggest including the build configuration or the exact command you are using. And make sure you're not using an ancient version of `r.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

As discussed in the comments, the solution is to pull the declaration of `i` out of the `for` loop structure:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

*Opinion: Since [there is no functional difference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) between the two ways of declaring `i`, it's funny that they are interpreted as being different by r.js.*

---

You could of course also go with `Array.prototype.filter` to entirely dodge the problem:

```js
var myArray = ['item1', 'apple', 'item2', 'item3', 'bread', 'etc'];
myArray = myArray.filter(item => ! /^item/.test(item));
console.log(myArray);
```

Performing additional logic could also be done both before and after filtering by using `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```js
var myArray = ['item1', 'apple', 'item2', 'item3', 'bread', 'etc'];

/** @return {boolean} */
function filterFn(item, index) {
  console.log(`Doing additional stuff with: myArray[${index}] = ${item}`);
  return ! /^item/.test(item);
}

myArray = myArray.filter(filterFn);

myArray.forEach((item, index) => {
  console.log(`After: myArray[${index}] = ${item}`);
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the work-around, but the key is, i'm performing additional complex logic in the loop that needs to be performed from front to back.  I'm not just filtering.  I will go with a solution like what you posted, but I'm really asking if this is intended r.js behavior and if i'm coding to an anti-pattern.  I'd prefer using the loop as I am, if possible, because otherwise to perform the same additional logic will require looping 3 times instead of 1.

Comment: @MichaelLaVoie Allright, I'll try to think of another solution. By the way, have you tried declaring `var i;` outside of (before) the loop structure?

Comment: Hey Jeffrey, thanks for the suggestion of pulling the var i; outside the loop. that was a great idea and that one line solved my issue.  Although I'm still curious about r.js replacing the for() with a loop() function, I'm considering this solved as that was as painless as it gets.  Best wishes!

Comment: @MichaelLaVoie I'm curious what the output is now :)

Comment: The output is nearly identical except it scopes the "var i;" before declaring the loop function and the subsequent loop function execution.  this puts it in scope for both so edits made in the function get applied.

Comment: That's the thing. Even in the r.js result that you posted `i` is in scope of `_loop` it's function body. I just can't think of any good reason why it should be a parameter for an additional function scope.